# "Cannot call member function ... without object" inside unevaluated context - GCC bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

The following program compiles fine with Clang:

```
template< typename > struct X
{
  void foo() {}

  auto bar() -> decltype( X::foo() )
  {
    return foo();
  }
};

int main()
{
  X<int>().bar();
}
```

But GCC 4.8.1 gives:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct X<int>':
main.cpp:13:10:   required from here
main.cpp:5:34: error: cannot call member function 'void X< <template-parameter-1-1> >::foo() [with <template-parameter-1-1> = int]' without object
   auto bar() -> decltype( X::foo() )
                                  ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:13:12: error: 'struct X<int>' has no member named 'bar'
   X<int>().bar();
            ^
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/307f5bfa29ab8d45)

When I change the code to `decltype( std::declval<X>().foo() )` GCC compiles it.

Is this a bug in GCC (and is there an existing bug report for it or should report it?) or is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in gcc, well-known to me at least. I would be surprised if there is no report already, but I don't know (I didn't bother but simply avoided it).

Comment: `decltype( this->foo() )` compiles whereas `decltype( foo() )` does not. Strong hint for a compiler bug IMO.

Comment: Possibly this bug? http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57543

Comment: @DyP Thanks for digging this one up, I added a comment to the bug report in the hope it helps them to track it down.

Comment: @DanielFrey clang 3.4 (trunk 194324) compiles your code and the executable runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this bug? [decltype needs explicit 'this' pointer in member function declaration of template class with trailing return type](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57543) – dyp

[Fixed.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57543#c8)